# How do I send data from 4 text fields to a Derby Database in Netbeans using Java

Tags: java, database, registration, derby

I have a registration page where information for a customer can be entered into 4 text fields, i.e. Customer name, customer address, customer email and customer contact number.

I was wondering how to get the data from the text fields and into the Derby Database in netbeans using Java.

Comment: By writing some code. What _specifically_ prevents you from writing the code yourself? This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to get the text from the fields first, so as follows:

```
//Replace the textfield names with your textfield variable names
String customerName = txtFieldCustomerName.getText();
String customerAddress = txtFieldCustomerAddress.getText();
String customerEmail = txtFieldCustomerEmail.getText();
String customerContactNumber = txtFieldCustomerContactNumber.getText();
```

Now that we have all the data, we can perform a database insert

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
try {
   Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
        //Get a connection
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myDB;create=true;user=me;password=mine");//Replace this with your information to your database

   //now we have a connection, we can perform the insert
   pstmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into TABLE_NAME_HERE (customerName, customerAddress, customerEmail, customerContactNumber) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
   pstmt.prepareString(1, customerName);
   pstmt.prepareString(2, customerAddress);
   pstmt.prepareString(3, customerEmail);
   pstmt.prepareString(4, customerContactNumber);

   pstmt.executeUpdate(); //execute the insert
} catch(SQLException sqle) {
   sqle.printStackTrace();
}
finally { //close the connection after everything is done.
   try {
      con.close();
      pstmt.close();
   } catch(SQLException sqle) {
       sqle.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```